# How to display current value of <select> in label without change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I current have a label which displays the selected option from a dynamic select dropdown, but it only shows onchange. I'd like it to be able to show the current value when the page loads too. I tried switching 'change' for 'load' with no luck. Here is my current set-up:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByName('filename'), function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML = this.value;
  });
});
```

```html
<select class="select1" name="filename" id="filename">
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>
<label id="mylabel"></label>
```

Comment: Put `document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML = this.value` outside of the `addEventListener` call too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan well not outside like this, but by changing `this` with the element

Answer (score 1):

You did say when the page loads, well it's as simple as this...

```
<body onload="mylabel.innerHTML=filename.value;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is what you want, I just have added the line outside the function

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByName('filename'), function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML = this.value;
  });
});
document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML = document.getElementById('filename').value;
```

```html
<select class="select1" name="filename" id="filename">
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>
<label id="mylabel"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByName('filename'), function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML = this.value;
  });
});

$('#mylabel').html($('#filename').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select1" name="filename" id="filename">
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>
<label id="mylabel"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the loop?

```js
let e = document.getElementById("filename");
let x = document.getElementById('mylabel');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
   x.innerHTML = e.value;    
   e.addEventListener('change', function(){
      x.innerHTML = this.value;
   });
});
```

```html
<select class="select1" name="filename" id="filename">
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>
<label id="mylabel"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

applying DRY (don't repeat yourself): name the click handler and then call it manually during initialization.  alternatively you can trigger the change even manually during initialization.

code

```
$(function() {
  // event handler on change
  $('#filename').change(mylabel_update);

  // update mylabel to show filename
  function mylabel_update() {
    $('#mylabel').html($('#filename').value);
  } 

  // initialize option A - call the function directly
  mylabel_update();

  // initialize option B - force the change event (don't need the named fn)
  $('#filename').trigger('change');
});
```